# Replace contents of two different sized data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame containing some data. For example,

```
a.df <- data.frame(C = 5, D = 7)
```

I want to create another data frame with P columns and a single row of zeros, e.g.

```
 b.df <- data.frame(A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, E = 0)
```

but the number of columns is computed, so the b.df data frame cannot be explicitly created as shown above.

I then want to replace the values in the first (only) row of b.df with the values in the first row of the corresponding columns in a.df (in this case, b.df[1,”C”] = 5 and b.df[1,”D”] = 7, but other columns remain zero and the column names are preserved.

Another solution would be to add zero columns to a.df, but in any event I need a data frame (or named vector) that has P elements with a single row with all zero elements except columns C and D.

I have tried a number of approaches but I keep losing column names and run into other issues. Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `b.df[1, match(names(a.df), names(b.df))] <- a.df; b.df`

Comment: Thanks, Richard. That appears to do what I need.